# Should I use multiple initialization for neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am confused with Neural Network Initialization during learning TensorFlow.

There are two reasons I found it should perform **Random Initialization**:

1. Avoid symmetry breaking. (Use initialization)
2. Avoid bad local minima. (Use **multiple** initialization and choose the best one)

The first reason I know why it can avoid symmetry breaking already but the second reason still let me very confuse.

In TensorFlow [Getting Started](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) tutorial, they use random initialization but **NOT** multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

They use initialization only once. Then train. No new initialization as this would overwrite the trained weights.

Once your neural net converges (=finds "good" results) you might save those weights and start again from scratch (=new initialization) and compare the results with the results from the first training process.

You could repeat this a couple of times and then use the weights from the best training (=starting from the "best" initialization).

The reason why you do this is because initialization is an important step to perform well, depending on the architecture of your neural net. So you might say: Every human gets born only once. But if you want to breed a new Einstein you might need many humans to find one.

Comment: Thank you, @friesel. But why I use `tf.truncated_normal` to initialize the weights **only once**, it always get the 99.2% test accuracy in [that](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) dataset? Is this situation called a **Convex Function**?